# Search with Varbinary in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, full-text-search

I am new to SQL.
I have stored file attachments of mailing service in Database as Data Type Varbinary.
I converted file to Byte Array in C# then saved it into Varbinary column.
I need to search content in those attachments.
Using Full-Text Search, it works fine, but in cases when a document has another document embedded(like in MS Word) within it then the search in those documents fail.
Any ideas on how the embedded document is saved when converted to Byte Array or Varbinary so i can apply search over it. I tried converting search strings to hexa code, varbinary type and using like (was just trying to get something to work).
Any ideas ?

Comment: Give us some code You used to get this.

Comment: SELECT [id]
      ,[FileName]
      ,[FileExtension] FROM [temp_FullTextSearchTest]
where CONTAINS (ImageData,'SearchText')

Comment: It works in embedded documents but not when the document is converted to icons. Say if i simply insert an object in MS Word, it is displayed as complete document within the parent doc. By when i right click and convert the document to display as icon, the search stops working